# New Tag Not Properly Set to Cope With Text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I tried to update my profile and found the following with the newly styled tag:

[image]

Before and after is just one white space. It seems the spacing isn't properly set to cope with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin is definitely off. I put in a fix for this, will be on live after our next prod build(within 24hrs). Thanks.

Comment: I'll be watching you !!

Comment: Fixed. It looks like if the right margin is bigger than the left or is that an optical illusion?

Comment: Is it an optical illusion?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra do you have the url to a question that has tags in the post body?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but these on tags it shows: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I see the problem now. I'll do some additional fixing. thanks.

Comment: While you're at it, can you align the tag badge to the normal badge? See my profile for that: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/29140/jacob-jan-tuinstra?tab=badges

Comment: Can you change the background of the tag badge as well, to make it stand out more to the rest of the badges? [so] and [su] have that also.

Comment: Sorry there Jin, on the last remark I got carried away. That's  not a glitch in the matrix of course !!

Comment: Should I file for a separate request Jin, to align the tag badge with the normal badge?